# How can I edit my Stack Overflow CV to use my profile picture?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I want my CV to use my profile picture instead of gravatar. Apart from changing the gravatar, is there a way to use Stack Exchange uploaded profile picture to be used in CV as well?

Answer (score 8):

No, Gravatar seems to be the only way. But you can add another email to your Gravatar account with a different picture, if you're using gmail you can try something like name+careers@gmail.com, then create an alias.

Comment: Isn't merely specifying "name+careers" as an email address effectively creating an alias for name@gmail.com?

Comment: Apparently so ... https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

I've marked this as [status-deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) because we're aware of the pain points here but we don't have the development resource to dedicate to it right at this moment.

We are working on the new [Introducing the Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story) feature which would address this, albeit it in a change the underlying mechanism entirely sort of way.