# Introducing the Developer Story

Tags: discussion, profile-page, developer-story

> ### TL;DR;
>
> We're replacing CVs with something you can use even if you aren't currently looking for a job.

---

> ***Update (Jan 4):** added an FAQ section to address some common questions & concerns*

---

We've had a lot of announcements lately about changes to Stack Overflow, including the addition of [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow), the [Power of Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow), and our plan to [serve programmers better](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better) by integrating [Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow).

[image: we're back]

We started by [updating the profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309870/new-expanded-profile-information) so you could show off a bit about who you are but now we're expanding this further into something we think will be called the **Developer Story**.

### What the heck is a Developer Story?

I'm glad you asked! It's the way we envision you showcasing every aspect of your developer identity. Here's what we think it will look like:

> [image: Developer story mockup]

### Who is the Developer Story for?

Stack Overflow is the place where developers come to build and share knowledge, and as a result, build reputation for those contributions.  It's also a place where you can help write Documentation, join a Team that you contribute to, or even look for a job. Now, with the new developer story, **we're making it about who you are and what you do,** and that's available to everyone regardless of how you use the site.

[image: everybody gets one]

We've designed this to be a better way for developers to share what they've built and done, regardless of whether or not they're job-hunting now.  We know that ~40% of developers who sign up are interested in hearing about job opportunities, but for the rest of you, it may just be a way to show off to your peers.

- If you're looking for the job you deserve, this is an upgrade to our old "Careers CV". It's designed to emphasize what you've built and technology you've used, and remove the useless stuff that traditional resumes contained
- Got a job you love? Share your accomplishments in a way that wasn't possible until now. Your story is all about **your** journey as a developer.

Whether you are purely a Q&A user or you are using your Stack Overflow profile to show potential employers, the story gives everyone a way to show off how awesome they are as a developer.

### We already have a profile, why do we need a Developer Story?

The [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover-part-one) isn't going anywhere. Every user gets one when they signup for Stack Overflow; it is a blend of your biography, your tags, and, if you provided one, your job title and where you work.  Many of our users have a completed profile, but **it doesn't provide a full picture of who you are, and we're trying to fix that.**

The developer story goes much further by giving you the ability to provide more details of your history as a developer.  We want developers to tell their story, their way, by highlighting:

- Your current role and prior roles
- The technologies that you use, and the tags that you participate in on Stack Overflow
- Public artifacts like open source projects, applications & software, books or blogs you've written

We know that when developers talk about what they do, they'll share: What they build? Where they build it? And what tech was used?  The answers to these questions don't fit in the current profile, but they have a place in your story.  The new story gives a bigger picture of who you are and what you are proud of.  Whether it's the school you are attending or have attended, your GitHub activity, your open source projects or apps; you'll be able to have everything you’ve done or are doing in a single place for the others to see.

Most of your story will be visible to people viewing your profile. But if you are someone who wants to keep your Stack Overflow activity separate from your career activity, don't worry: there will be privacy options to help you control who can see what.

### FAQ

**What problem does this solve?**

- It gives you a way to showcase your skills, and maybe one day find a job
- It replaces the existing, traditionally-structured CV with something that you can use even if you aren’t currently looking for a job
- It does a better job of showing what matters to developers and employers than traditional CVs by focusing on what you’ve done and not just where you’ve worked or studied

**What happens to existing CVs just brought in from Careers?**

Developer Stories are designed to replace CVs. We’ll have more details on this in the future, but all existing CVs will be carried over into this system, and we’ll preserve all existing privacy settings, so if your profile is private the Developer Story will also be.

**Is Stack Overflow becoming a social network?**

No. There will be no friends, lists, or other social connections, except indirectly through companies you have worked together at. This is just an expansion of the profile.

**What if I want to keep it private?**

Privacy will not be an issue: just like with existing CVs you can make it completely private, or hidden on the site but searchable to employers.

**What if I don’t want one?**

If you don’t want to share your history, then you don’t have to. Filling out the developer story is completely optional.

**Will I still be able to export to PDF?**

Yes, this feature will continue to work with the new developer story.

**How will this work with my activity on other Stack Exchange network sites?**

For now, the Developer Story page will only exist on Stack Overflow, but it will allow you to feature top answers from other network sites.

### What's Next?

We think we've found a better way to display your history and what you've done, but **we need your help to figure out what might be missing.**

- What else do you want to show off as a developer? Either to the developer community or to employers?
- What are you proud of that you'd want to showcase?

This won't be rolled out for 6-8 weeks but, in the meantime, let us know what you think!

Comment: Can we adding custom "stories" in the timeline?

Comment: I'm drawing a lot of parallels between this and my Stack Overflow CV. I don't want to have to enter the same information in two different places...

Comment: Uhm... [wasn't this the whole idea of the new profile page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover-part-one)? And I thought [Stack Overflow was not a social network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/is-stack-overflow-a-social-networking-site)...

Comment: @hichris123: Yeah, I thought this looked remarkably familiar, too, as if it was inspired by [a certain social networking site](https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+timeline&tbm=isch)...

Comment: @BoltClock As I mentioned, this is going to be an upgrade to the Careers CV. You will not be entering information in 2 places.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to sell the site to LinkedIn, instead of morphing into it step by step?

Comment: @bluefeet: So does it pull information from both my CV and my Q&A profile automatically?

Comment: @BhargavRao What do you mean "custom stories"?

Comment: @bluefeet Can we have our own Subtitles there ... i.e. .. "education","certification" and so on are present, Can we add our own?

Comment: @BhargavRao There will be preset fields for you to fill in similar to what there is in the existing Careers CV.  I don't believe we would initially have your own subtitles.

Comment: How will this be moderated? What happens if I add nasty content to my developer story? Will we be treating these like about-me text, or like text in a post?

Comment: So basically this is just a redesign of the current CV feature on Jobs?

Comment: "6-8 somethings" Somehow sounds much more vague than the usual 6-8 weeks... Getting more realistic with deadlines?

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yes. We know that developers like to share specific things that the existing resume is missing.  This is a new way to display what you as a developer want to showoff.

Comment: So... if this is only really for Jobs, can we have an option to hide it?

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, options to keep your story hidden will be available.

Comment: @bluefeet What specific things is the existing CV feature missing (besides the new look of course) that Developer Stories adds? All of the categories in the screenshot (Apps, Education, Positions, Answers, Blog Posts, Certifications, Open Source Projects, Books Read, etc) already exist in the CV feature. The layout is just a bit different.

Comment: @hichris123 The profile is great for a high-level overview of you but the Developer Story goes a bit further allowing you to give more details about your career which doesn't fit into the existing profile.

Comment: @Ajedi32 We'll add more features later in the developer story. But right now the main difference is that you can use it without looking for a job so it does mean Stack Overflow gives you the opportunity to have a great profile online that shows what you've done / who you are as a developer, which wasn't the case with the current profile. For future releases we want to add more things to this story, real things that developers need and this is why we're making this post, to see if something is missing :)

Comment: So it's StackedInBook?

Comment: Kidding aside I actually like this as a person who is looking to move into a developer role this would be quite useful to showcase something. Plus people won't let me plug my USB drive into their laptop so my epic presentation won't do the job.....

Comment: I also thought new profile page was enough for that. At least there should be opt in opt out option

Comment: I think unless you're going to merge all the SE sites together, this misses an opportunity to come up with a cohesive profile of who you are. Click Here to see how awesome I am on SO, but I also administer servers so here's a glimpse of my BOFHness on ServerFault but I also do wicked things with databases, check out that version of me on DBA.SE. Please, completely disregard my bio though on Project Management - I was going through an experimental phase.

Comment: @billinkc You'll be able to include content from other sites similar to what you can now in your Careers CV.  Then if you want to include your experimental PM phase you can.

Comment: Does this remind anyone else of the Facebook timeline? Doesn't that disturb anyone else?

Comment: At least we're not using [round profile photos](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56730/why-are-the-profile-pictures-rounded-nowadays), even though we've inexplicably decided to adopt the centre-aligned profile page from *every single social network*.

Comment: SO is trying too hard to become a Facebook for developers, or a LinkedIn with Q&A. What kinds of "stories" will I have? "Trying COBOL for the first time! YOLO!" If I have anything to share, I will tell my friends in chat, not sync SO with my Facebook Timeline

Comment: How about implementing / fixing things that would be useful to users asking and moderating questions and answers, rather than something that is useful to becoming LinkedIn?  At no point in my SO experience have I had a problem discovering things about power users I'm interested in; the information is already readily available on the profile, on GitHub, or on their personal site.

Comment: It is also possible to indicate what you have done in a traditional CV. Playing devil's advocate.

Comment: "It replaces the existing, traditionally-structured CV with something that you can use even if you aren’t currently looking for a job" except we can already make a CV on careers and say we're not looking, so that's not an improvement.

Comment: "It does a better job of showing what matters to developers and employers than traditional CVs" how?  Besides "focusing on what you've done", which I'm pretty sure my Careers page already does, what *specifically* makes this better?  This just looks like an unfocused mess trying to imitate other sites.

Comment: @Normal I thought that already happened. Aren't we LinkedIn's API tech support?

Comment: Each time the community says "isn't this a social network?" you *say* "NO!", but the features keep marching in. Teams, now this. Just saying no doesn't make it so.

Comment: what i liked about this site was that it wasn't like so many other sites with extensive self-promotion tools. le sigh. so much for that.

Comment: It looks like StackExchange has got no CCB (Configuration Control Board) and no vision. Change for the sake of change, mission creep, and faux pas after faux pas? No problem! Folks, you haven't extricated yourself from the _licensing_ tar pit yet! What's seriously missing is some mechanism to conduct limited opinion surveys before committing your shiny new plan to meta SO/meta SE.

Comment: Off-topic, but it took me far too long to realise those were buttons in that final image.

Comment: * The design for the fancy 'Story' is non-linear and interactive. Please name two HR departments that like non-linear CVs.

* Abuse of personal pronoun 'I' makes a potential employer think twice. 'I ate tacos this morning'. 'I am reading _How to make salad with jQuery?_' If it looks unprofessional, it **is** unprofessional.

* What's that 'public artefact' thing? Is it something tangible (like 'public artefacts' I collect after my dog) or intangible? Is it a book I wrote or a concert I took part in?

Comment: Is SE finally entering the we-have-nothing-left-to-do-so-lets-make-stuff-up-to-keep-our-jobs phase? Netscape, Norton's, Devshed, Winamp, it happens to the best of them.

Comment: @bluefeet In chat, it was mentioned that the real purpose of this is to create some sort of revenue stream for SE (which: cool). Is this true and, *if* it is, then why is it not mentioned in this post?

Comment: We already *have* a revenue stream, @JasonC. This might help indirectly, but only insofar as it helps folks create better CVs. Also, first we have to finish shaving this yak.

Comment: @Shog9 Well then I might indirectly +1 this.

Comment: As a more serious answer, @Jason... This is part of the initiative [Tim laid out in this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better), the gist of which is: take side projects we've tried in the past that've sorta worked and give them the proper SO treatment. Part of that is Careers integration, which is already in place (Jobs) but in a really, really hacky manner; the next step is to take the pieces and replace the blind Careers copies with stuff that's more generally-useful and less... weird and out of place.

Comment: "except indirectly through companies you have worked together at" - Please elaborate

Comment: I can’t say I care all that much for this feature, but the general reaction seems rather over the top. Careers/Jobs has been around for a while now; it isn’t new. The way recent changes have been *announced* seems likely to provoke contempt. The memes were cute when we wanted to nuke the close vote queue because they felt relevant and reinforced the community effort. Widely heralding the brilliance of every feature (profile page included) is just obnoxious. Still, it’s hard for me to care all that much. I don’t use Jobs; what’s the big deal? Worried how the money you didn’t pay is being spent?

Comment: +1 as this seems to make cv reading more interesting. This may be helpful for hr/dev people looking to hire. I dont really see this affecting the QA system in any way.

Comment: There's already a website which does this stuff.. it's called linkedIn

Comment: This is a death blow to Careers. Really. It was nice to have, but not anymore - at least for me. It's not just moving the cheese around, which is fine, it's making the cheese into yoghurt.

Comment: what problem does this solve? The current way careers.so profiles are rendered is almost perfect. It is simple, easy to read, and easy to follow, and pretty. I wish employers took my CV directly from careers.so instead of asking for linkedin (which is what you seem to be trying to turn careers into) or some other social network like website. Please please please don't do this. For the love of all the super awesome work you guys have done till now.

Comment: Raised an underlying problem on meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272391/another-third-place-preliminary-testing-for-stack-exchange-shiny-new-projects

Comment: The FAQ bullet point about solved problems doesn't actually list any problem to solve. _""It gives you a way to showcase your skills, and maybe one day find a job"_ isn't a problem statement. _"Showcasing your skills on StackOverflow is difficult"_ is a problem statement (even if this problem doesn't really exist).

Comment: score +96/-96 sounds like a revenge of introverts (yes I am introvert myself)

Comment: "Do one thing and do it well" - IMHO this is why G+ fails, and also why I feel this jobs/careers/timeline/whatevs mish-mash needs a more cohesive strategy before it's useful.

Comment: I can understand where this feature flow comes from. Stack Exchange has attracted new investors who want to monetize Stack Overflow user base and question base. Some of those investors may be not exactly bright, and hence they want SE to emulate LinkedIn and Facebook and whatnot. **They have no original ideas, but they want their money (and more) back**.

Comment: @DeerHunter We aren't trying to emulate LinkedIn and Facebook; we've had the Careers product living off in a siloed universe for years at this point, and we no longer think that's a good idea. We want to incorporate our products into a single unified platform, but *also* make some changes so that features are more broadly appealing outside of very narrow use cases (like looking for a job). Yes, our investors expect a return on their investment eventually, but nothing of substance is changing in that regard: display ads + selling Careers products to companies has *always* been how we make money

Comment: @Laura - to sell Careers, you have to have a willing user base. Most of the responses here are confused by your decision to replace CVs with Developer Stories. It's your business, and your decisions, even if you want to strangle your revenue source...

Comment: It definitely has some flaws but why criticize it now? If it turns out to be a flop we can always remove it later.

Comment: SE's value is providing useful information, with Magical Internet Points to encourage people. If we wanted a place about the people instead of the information, we'd go to Facebook/LinkedIn.

Comment: Here's a better tl;dr: `Our current CVs really aren't that great. Careers did a decent job, but still won't replace [monster/linked-in/etc]. To help avoid wasting everyone's time with yet another resume, we are going to replace the CV with something which should be more useful, a developer story. This will allow you to easily include your SE contributions into your CV/story and hopefully create an easier, more relevant resume, based on SE.`  It conveys 1) what is happening, 2) why its happening, and 3) how its happening.

Comment: If I wanted a blog, I'd get a blog. If I wanted to ask/answer questions, I'd go on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My question is most companies still want your CV.  Will this export out to a nice CV format?

Comment: @JonH The export feature will still be available and employers will still have the ability to view your CV as a sorted (traditional resume) view.  Those features will still be available, this is just an alternate view for you as the developer.

Comment: @bluefeet - If that is the case then I see absolutely no issue with this whatsoever.  I am not sure everyone understands this, at least from the comments and answers no..no they don't understand it.  If at the end of the day this exports to a CV, which is what 99.9% of all companies expect, then proceed.  This is nice, and I'd like to opt-into this thing.  How do I gain access to this?

Comment: @JonH most companies will expect a more standard CV, not something like this. This makes it considerably more difficult to skim and get a feeling about a person quickly than a CV since it moves information randomly, puts it into multiple columns, etc. I would not want to submit this to any non "super hip" company as a CV/resume..

Comment: @JonH We're still developing it and hope to have something for beta soonish.  The point of this was to allow the community to see it, get feedback.

Comment: @enderland - You don't show them your developer story, you export your CV which to me sounds like they are still keeping the format of the CV.

Comment: @bluefeet - Great, I'm a willing candidate to test if you guys like.  To me this is a much needed feature.  I see it as something very clean and positive.

Comment: I don't think anyone actually wants this. I know that's not a very constructive thing to say, but this isn't a very constructive feature for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShadowWizard How is this a "death blow" to Careers? People don't want jobs?

Comment: @Hynes you are approaching from a perspective of, "I get the problem we're addressing and why this is valuable." The post is approaching it as, "look we have a new shiny object to share!" -- a classic problem trying to persuade others. The need is present to you, the creators, who presumably have had discussions about this internally. But the people you are trying to convince need to first be informed/convinced of the problem/reasons this suggestion exists. This is a common problem with persuading others - we act as if the motivations behind a suggestion are given information - but it isn't.

Comment: .. seeing shiny new features without any reasoning why they are needed is probably why this feature is so heavily downvoted. No one sees a need for it, and to top it off, it looks like Facebook. You __have__ to build a case for why something is needed when trying to persuade others. This doesn't build a case at all, the "why its needed" is a list of features. Features aren't a compelling reason, generally. It's not going to be effective to drop changes on people without any explanation of why you are doing it (especially when the Facebook-like-ness factor exists).

Comment: I have reservations about the strategy behind the recent changes (see my answer below) but I disagree that the team needs to build a giant case to justify every feature they create (even though it would be nice to be able to see the internal thought processes that led to it). This new view conveys a developer's professional life much better than a traditional CV. In fact, it seems like an appropriate, somewhat visionary *reinvention* of the CV for digital media.

Comment: (cont'd) It allows for the addition of major and minor achievements in an unordered way that would look weird on paper. It gives a visual chronological overview that's much more fun to parse, and each step can be extended infinitely (e.g. by adding links and pictures for each step). The importance of each step can be controlled by the amount of text, pictures, and links we give them. Etc. etc. And if we are above Facebook, why should we care whether a feature here resembles something that was created there?

Comment: @Hynes of course they want jobs. But that Developer Story is not a CV. It does not look like a CV. And without CV, I see little point in Careers. Might be just me, might be just over panic over a major change, but that is how I feel at the moment

Comment: @ShadowWizard Understandable. Not liking the idea of a Developer Story doesn't negate the value of Careers IMO. The Developer Story might be a poor idea for Careers.

Comment: @Hynes wait, the Developer Story can be "standalone", i.e. for any user, regardless of Careers?

Comment: That's the idea, @ShadowWizard. The hope is that we can make something that fulfills the *conceptual* requirements for a CV without being... Y'know, a horrible pile of facts and dates that you keep around out of necessity but are pretty sure no one ever reads in full and which you tend to assume are clumsy fictions when receiving them from others. Something more like a portfolio, a showcase, not a relic. If that works out, it'll be something that a *lot* of folks will find interesting... Although that *may not actually include employers!*

Comment: Why make a q&a site look more and more like a social network?

Comment: @enderland: At least SO gives us the option to opt-out indefinitely (/ not opt in). I'm looking at you, Facebook "Top stories"!

Comment: I for one, loved the ole CV feature. It allowed me to create a CV *with a URL* to send to people as needed. It fit the traditional *we need a CV from you, preferably one we can print* niche perfectly. I doubt they want to see a developer story sent to them. Don't get rid of the CV, *please*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure what's old/new here (I'm catching up), but the vanity URLs aren't going anywhere. I added that route myself and it works today. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/cv/ncraver

Comment: @NickCraver the post implies Dev Stories are to replace CVs: *It replaces the existing, traditionally-structured CV*

Comment: You have a great product. Please don't alienate your user base by tacking on unwanted features - _particularly_ while removing wanted ones.

Comment: @Emrakul We already have CVs as a part of Jobs, this is just a revamp of that feature. If you don't use SO to find jobs, then you don't have to use this feature.

Comment: @bluefeet I'm concerned about the impact on overall SE health. If these feature changes alienate top users, then they affect everyone, even if I never touch Careers. Features don't live in bubbles.

Comment: @bluefeet I'm curious how you're taking this reaction from the meta community.

Comment: @canon My blue feet are just fine, thank you for asking. But seriously, the feedback on this is incredibly helpful to how we are going to move forward.  We brought this to the community to get thoughts and feedback, good or bad.

Comment: Now we are getting a new Facebook, Story, Wall, Whatever!

Comment: So everyone disliked this and it still goes through? =/

Comment: omg -47? Wow! new low?

Comment: I tried it, it's not for me. How do I completely delete it?

Comment: Feels like someone at SO needs to review OOP design principles, specifically the whole "do one thing" part of it. SO should do 1 thing, and do it well. That thing is dealing in computer science knowledge, not marketing resumes and backstories.

Comment: I thought its something new and the existing "Traditional View", which I used and liked a lot, will remain the same. However, you have mixed the two and removed useful features from the "Traditional View" which is not what I expected. The developer store is more like an online profile which you can't and shouldn't print and send out to employers. Employers need 2 page CVs which is what the traditional view provided. Pls bring it back. Thanks

Comment: So reputation has a purpose and mostly thats to make spam, Graffiti and Defacing less likely and moderation easier. Job postings, CV's, Developer Story...Have no place on SO. Feature should be locked since it's not appropriate for SO since its not focused on Programming.

Comment: @David  There are plenty of users who use those features and find them beneficial.  They serve a purpose in that they help developers find a job that they love; you aren't forced to use them and you can simply ignore it.

Comment: @bluefeet as pointed out by another user. Plenty of Users may find it useful for your Cellphone to be 6 foot tall and have a freezer section... doesnt mean its still a cellphone. A freezer doesnt belong in a Cellphone reguardless of wether people find it beneficial or useful. SO is a Q&A for programmers they need to stop trying to make it a Social Networking Job Board

Comment: It would be interesting to know which companies are SO users applying to that are still preferring the 40+ year old paper-compatible CVs and why. I mean I realize not everybody can or wants to work at Facebook/Google/Amazon/Yelp/etc. but all of my clients since 2013 were just literally people cold calling me after seeing my linkedin....(maybe things work differently in the freelance/consulting world, but do they really?)

Answer (score 298):

Just my (small) two cents.

Personally, I'm not a huge fan of this idea. So, if this does indeed go ahead, I'd like to be able to opt-out of this fully. Or even better, follow the same procedure as Winter Bash where users have to explicitly opt-in.

Comment: Hide all teh tings!

Comment: Seriously guys, by adding so many (unnecessary?) new features in the end you will transform SO to something less attractive at least for the devs. Sometimes you should keep things minimal and not overload it with new (uncalled for) features.

Comment: @Giorgi It's not a new feature, it's an upgrade of an existing feature (Careers CV). And to your point, we're still working hard to make Q&A better and we'll continue doing it.

Comment: @StéphaneMartin Ok but at least it should be optional, and privacy has to be accounted for. My point is if you invent mobile phone and it is successful no need to add features to it slowly such that in the end it transforms into a refrigerator say (which can still make calls of course), and everyone stops using it :)

Comment: @Giorgi We'll take care of the privacy and you'll be able to hide yours on SO :) (and manage your privacy)

Comment: @StéphaneMartin You may want to make it more clear in the proposal that it will be a replacement for the developer CV. It seems to be a common misconception that this will be in addition to everything else.

Comment: @Giorgi *My point is if you invent mobile phone and it is successful no need to add features to it slowly such that in the end it transforms into a refrigerator say (which can still make calls of course)* Ooooh NO! I'm not using a refrigerator that can still make calls.

Comment: @Giorgi, *Seriously guys, by adding so many (unnecessary?) new features in the end you will transform SO...* - Yes, new features will transform SO and the web. It's the way that community operates and some of the features might end up pulling away from the main site sometimes. If that happens and is bad, it can be a learning experience for the company and community

Comment: @Giorgi All I want to do is answer questions and yell at people that ask questions wrong. *And I'm all outta questions*.

Comment: @RobertGrant didn't get the joke :) Jakar:Yep but people can voice opinion to prevent mistakes

Comment: @Giorgi Robert's joke may be a reference to [Duke Nukem](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Duke_Nukem). Search for "bubble gum". :)

Comment: @Cypher Which in turn is actually a reference to 'They Live' https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/They_Live

Comment: I would also appreciate an explicit opt-in, I don't want to be pushed into this like when Facebook came up with 'News Feed' (puts gun against own skull)

Answer (score 238):

**I do not like this idea.**

Our goal is not to show off or present our personal achievements, that's what "rep-addicts" do. It is to build a useful and comprehensive set of answers to programming problems.

How would the change you propose make the Internet or at least Stack Overflow a better place? It is all about dragging focus away from the site's core (which is concentrating on clear and easy-to-find information) towards a place where everything you do is collected in your personal portfolio of actions. That's a social network.

Please remember that users are not our most valuable resource. It's the content posted by them.

*Please note: I can't deal with words, so I stole some of them [from Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258739/3751577). He really hits the spot with that post, although on a different topic.*

Comment: The internet is not a zero-sum game. Adding a developer story is, to me, a logical complement to StackOverflow, and I don't believe it takes anything away from SO. If you're not interested in it, you don't need to use it. Assuming of course that SO isn't going to be overlaid with an obnoxious developer story pop-up every time you visit. If SO can provide valuable information *and* a source of candidate or a better way to showcase my skills, then that's a win-win to me. I think that does make the internet a better place.

Comment: "How would the change you propose make the Internet a better place?" - It gives developers better tools for showing their past and **getting a better job in the future**. Remember, [Stack Overflow isn't just a Q&A site anymore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/). We're expanding to provide more and better tools for developers. This answer is great *if* we were only focusing on Q&A, but that's no longer true. The feature is a great addition to the Jobs section being integrated. Not to mention, it's completely optional.

Comment: @ColinYoung: _"The internet is not a zero-sum game"_ It's not far off. I'm already at a huge disadvantage in the jobs market because I do not have an active GitHub profile. The last thing I need is for SO to become yet-another-thing-I-need-to-have-a-complete-and-active-profile-on in order not to be completely left behind.

Comment: Also keep in mind, that while a few companies might love this for their hiring, the overwhelming majority of jobs/hires will _still_ be at other places which won't use this system. So most of us not applying for the latest-and-greatest-tech-shop will have to do yet another online thing...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Your SO reputation should be enough to "repay" for the fact that you are "missing" a GitHub profile ;)

Comment: @Giorgi: It does help!

Comment: You can't state what "our goal" is, only what "your goal" is. In your first sentence you acknowledge many SE members contribute for different reasons to you ('rep-addicts') and it's rather arrogant to suggest that just because you do not want to promote yourself through SO, others don't.

Answer (score 90):

What problem does this solve?

It seems it is solving this one:

> Stack Overflow doesn't allow you to have a social media profile/resume

Rather than a clear, tangible *problem* that I, as a user and contributor to Stack Exchange, want to have resolved by a social media profile/resume.

Comment: I think this is a pretty fair question. Any feature request that comes from the community gets **immediately** challenged by the question "what problem does this solve?" and I can't see any reason we shouldn't ask the same of the features being imposed rather than requested. The same question is asked [elsewhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313968/229044) but that answer starts with a much more polarizing statement.

Comment: @meagar & enderland: Agree this is a fair question that wasn't explicitly answered in the post. We've added it to the FAQ section.

Comment: @DavidFullerton: Except... not really. Your "what problem does this solve" section lists what you perceive to be the benefits of the new feature, but does not name a problem that exists without it.

Answer (score 78):

I don't personally like this idea. It is explicitly stated that this will not replace the profile, but that's *exactly* what it is. It's a second profile page dressed up to look like a mix between LinkedIn and Facebook. It brings nothing new to the table and doesn't seem to do much of anything better than the aforementioned social networks and profile page or the current CV page.

I feel like this does a few things poorly:

1. It distracts from the core of the site, which is Q&A. I get the push recently with Jobs/Careers. It makes sense and, for the most part, I feel SO has done it fairly well and the changes have been mostly good. But this feels more like Jobs is encroaching on the Q&A which is highly disappointing
2. When the Teams feature was first announced, this was included in the post:

   > People can only ask questions about the team on the team page. Wait, does this mean Stack Overflow is a social network? Emphatically no.

   This type of page, integrated more tightly into the main site feels more and more like a social network. We're no longer sharing our knowledge with each other, we're sharing our lives. I do not support that direction for SO and I very much hope that this is reversed.
3. It is quite tightly integrated into the profile. Currently, there is just a button (not a navigation tab) to my CV, which makes sense. Jobs *is not* SO and I have seen it said time and time again that there is no intention for it to be. The CV itself is only half-styled to look like SO and feels separate.

   This puts it as one of the pages of your profile. It is now actually part of SO. It completely looked like SO. You're not leaving SO and going to SO Jobs/Careers, you're on SO and looking at someone's resume. I think it's distracting and unneeded. Will Jobs link over to this page when a company looks me up? If that's the case, you're now leaving Jobs to go to SO as well.
4. The name is fairly awkward, very generic and, again, lends itself to a feature of a social network, not a Q&A site.

This feels like an attempt to merge Jobs and StackOverflow, whether it is intentional or not. And while Jobs is a decent product and one that I have used (or at least filled out) for a couple years, I really, really hope this doesn't happen. StackOverflow is a Q&A site. It is not a careers site or a social network or a blog or anything like that. It is a place to ask and answer questions, to share your knowledge, and to become a better developer, which it most certainly has helped me become.

To be fair, I do like some of these features. Overall, I really like the design work (minus the SO header/navigation), especially the tag highlights, and would really like to see much of it integrated into the current CV.

Comment: For the record: It isn't a replacement for the profile, it is a replacement for the CV.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, I realize that and I make note of that in my post. I feel that it acts more as a second profile page than a CV the way it is currently setup, however. With some changes, mainly moving it out of the profile area, I think that (and most of my complaints) could be eradicated

Comment: Well, that's why we bring it up for discussion here. If we just designed stuff in private and a/b tested it to determine what was worth keeping, we'd end up with Facebook. [And no one needs that many crashes.](https://www.theinformation.com/facebooks-android-contingency-planning)

Comment: [Q&A isn't the sole focus of Stack Overflow anymore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/#q:-so,-why-the-change?). It may be a huge portion of it, but the intention is that Jobs and Documentation are brought under the same umbrella as equal partners, and equal partners deserve equal exposure on the profile page. This very much *is* a merge of Jobs into Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't see Jobs really fitting in though, @animuson. Q&A and docs are community efforts that, to some degree, benefit mankind. Jobs benefits employers, individual devs, and SO, because it's its main cash cow, thanks to IT being an insanely wealthy industry with a great demand for workers. Which is fine - but I *did* appreciate it being tastefully visually separated from the community efforts, and I'm not sure I like it being shoved into SO's main menu

Comment: @Pekka웃 Jobs is a more visible link, but it's still just a link (like the Careers links in the footer and site switcher are/were). If you don't want to use our job board, you don't have to. A lot of developers *are* looking for jobs, though, and we have a whole job board dedicated just to programming jobs, so we've made it easier for them to find.

Answer (score 67):

I downvoted, but not because I dislike the feature. Not at all - it looks awesome. I don't care whether it resembles a Facebook timeline or not; this one has a different and clearly defined purpose.

What I'm distrustful of, and why I downvoted, is the long-term direction that is implied by this growing fusion of Stack Overflow proper and Careers.

It was always understood that Careers exists to make the company money, while getting developers better jobs. And that's great! I hope it makes oodles of money.

But Careers is a fundamentally different service from the traditional Q&A, and the upcoming docs feature, in that it isn't about building a pool of knowledge that is for the ages (to a degree), a selfless effort of experts that transcends the individuals working on it (to a degree).

Careers exists to serve the selfish interests of employers, individual developers, and Stack Exchange the company. It is powered by the fact that IT is an industry with gigantic resources and a desperate need for apt workers. And that's all *fine* - but it should continue to be kept as separate as possible from Stack Overflow the community effort, without hiding it completely.

That ostensibly a great percentage of developers has expressed a need to use Careers (although I find the 40% statistic very questionable) doesn't change this fundamental difference.

Comment: I don't know what you want out of this based on what you have entered.  It is seperate, if you don't want a job or aren't looking for a job don't click the jobs link.

Comment: @JonH a giant link in the main menu doesn't satisfy my definition of "separate".

Comment: A giant link?  Its the same size as the other links.  Your rant is not justified if that is your issue...you're whining now.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Why do you "find the 40% statistic very questionable"? SO polled users with this question. Forty percent of those who responded said they were interested in hearing about job opportunities. Unless you're saying Stack Overflow is lying to you.

Comment: @JonH I'm not sure my post could be reasonably classified as "rant." I'm just feeling a certain amount of unease behind the recent changes around Careers, fearing that there may be a long-term strategy that is more influenced by VCs' goals than "making the Internet a better place" (and is designed to give Careers more emphasis in the ecosystem than it should have.) Whether that fear is justified, I don't know; it may not be. But right now, I have it

Comment: I understand the concern, but I think a lot of this comes down to how badly we've communicated the goals for and problems with Careers in the past. Internally, keeping it at arm's length has meant a lot of duplicated effort and a lot of wasted effort on both the Careers and core Q&A dev teams; this is bad for everyone - even if you're not interested in Careers, the fact that we've spent years pouring resources into people and projects that can't ever benefit Q&A should be worrying. That made sense when it was a couple people working on an experimental project, but... It ain't 2010 anymore.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Money is needed to pay rent, to pay for heat (it isn't cheap and NY is cold), to pay awesome programmers.  To me Q&A has not changed any differently than it has been (aside from great features).  I mean be honest, the Q&A here is pretty awesome.  It's amazingly fast, its amazingly simple, and each day minor changes are noticed that makes Q&A all the better.  If you were seeing some sort of changes that hindered Q&A I'd agree with you.  But I see quite the opposite.  I also see a lot of the developers / designers always mention that they are sticking to ensuring Q&A is awesome.

Comment: @Hynes I don't disbelieve the poll,  I'm just not sure it can/should be reasonably used as a justification for making Careers a super prominent feature.

Comment: Well, maybe that's part of the problem, @JonH. We've spent an awful lot of time trumpeting work like this (because we're in unknown territory and desperately need feedback), but not so much when it comes to the more incremental changes to Q&A - unless you're following [meta-tag:status-completed] across meta sites, changes there are a lot less noticeable. For years we've made a point to make *some* sort of improvement every week, but we're not always so good about announcing it. Maybe a year-end wrap-up would help?

Comment: @JonH `If you were seeing some sort of changes that hindered Q&A I'd agree with you. But I see quite the opposite.` that *is* a fair point.

Comment: @Shog9 - I think you are right...but you hit the nail on the head as you mentioned this is unknown territory.  I think this is a pretty natural thing, including the responses here.  It's pretty natural people become uncomfortable with changes they aren't accustomed too, especially big ones.  This is a very big one...the bigger one was integrating jobs into SO.  Truly I believe that the latter one so far to me is gaining traction.  Not just by me, but others on the site.  I don't have access to the analytics behind it, but I'd bet within time and within people becoming accustomed to things it..

Comment: ...will get better.

Comment: I am also removing my down vote because I see your issue more with the comments side of it.

Comment: For the record, I don't mind unknown territory at all. I don't agree with all those here who say that new things need to solve a clearly stated problem; many great innovations *didn't*. I just don't want to see the place subtly changed, long term, into a second coming of LinkedIn. With tens of millions of VC capital that eventually will want to see bottom line results, I think the community is somewhat justified in being distrustful about strategic changes - even *though* the team (at least those I know) is genuinely interested in building a product that makes the Internet better.

Comment: I'm sure more communication would do a lot to dissipate the problem @Shog9. Frequent blog posts; perhaps a separate podcast highlighting various teams within the company, and revealing some of the strategic thoughts behind whatever changes are happening? SO has always been super transparent about so many things, why not about strategy, too, to some extent?

Comment: @Pekka웃 could you elaborate on *why* the "growing fusion of Stack Overflow proper and Careers" is such a big source of discomfort for you? What specifically (features or behaviors) are you afraid we'll introduce? How would they make your life worse? We definitely need to communicate more and better, but it would also help to know in more detail what you're afraid we'll do so we can address those things head-on. (E.g., I don't want us to be like LinkedIn where anyone can pay us to message anyone with a profile. But that might not be what you mean when you say "like LinkedIn".)

Comment: You're gonna *love* the next podcast, @Pekka웃 - an interview with one of the developers behind Integration, and some discussions of the philosophy at work. To be released any day now.

Comment: @Laura I'll try to write something up later!

Comment: @Shog cool, looking forward to it. I still have loads of dirt to shovel and listening to podcasts alongside [is fun](https://twitter.com/Pekkanikolaus/status/678178810827808768)!

Comment: sounds like a project I undertook last year. Nothing like moving a hill by hand to make you appreciate the natural beauty of erosion.

Comment: @Shog9 ohhh yes. I learned to appreciate the purpose of diggers - even though I'm happy to do this without one, nothing better than free exercise

Comment: Just chiming in that I'd be interested in the podcast - hopefully they don't mention my dreaded name with all the bug reports - or maybe thats a good thing.

Comment: You'll just have to listen to find out...

Comment: @Shog9 curious where the podcasts are posted?  Are they now on the company blog?

Comment: Yup, @JonH. There's even a tag: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/tags/podcasts/

Comment: @Shog9 - No shout out or swag for me :-(...so sad!  It was a great podcast.

Answer (score 51):

My biggest concern is that StackOverflow is going to become a job search site. My last company actually blocked employees from visiting LinkedIn. Their reasoning was quite simply that there is only one reason that people visit that site. I'd hate to see StackOverflow start getting blocked by companies, especially in the tech industry, just because, "We know that ~40% of developers who sign up are interested in hearing about job opportunities" - a statement I find dubious. If true, then StackOverflow is now already waaaay different from the StackOverflow I signed up to.

Comment: You probably signed up to Stack Overflow to help developers and/or to get help, and that's still the case. We'll even do more features so people could help more & get more help :).

Comment: @StéphaneMartin - why don't you do those features instead of transmorphing SO into a social networking site in the first place?

Comment: @DeerHunter We're working on it. The developer story isn't the only project we're working on at the moment. I'm sorry but I don't see the social network here. You have no friends, no list, no special connections except teams, users can't follow ou, can't contact you, you shouldn't often update your dev. story as it's the highlights of your dev life...

Comment: @StéphaneMartin "You probably signed up to Stack Overflow to help developers and/or to get help" No, I certainly did not. I signed up for Stack Overflow because I agreed that creating a repository of lasting information, of *answers* to every programming question, is a noble goal that I could help with. Instead of facilitating this goal, Stack Exchange has encouraged "asking" (i.e. requesting the over-incentivized reputation-seekers to do your job for you) over answering, focused on quantity of quality, and made the quality bar harder to maintain as a moderator.

Comment: Becoming a social media site does not help achieve the original goal of creating valuable, lasting information. By focusing on "more features so people can help more", you further dilute the value in Stack Overflow. We don't need another Linked in, we need a site that helps programmers in the way the Stack Overflow was originally intended.

Comment: This point is very important. My colleagues might today be happy, or even proud, of my reputation on SO, as it appears I'm training to keep up with technologies and also able to solve problems. They wouldn't be so happy to see me polishing my public CV in order to leave them.

Comment: @DenysSéguret You'll be able to keep the Developer Story private similar to how you can keep your CV private to employers only.

Comment: @bluefeet I understand that, and it's important. My concern is about how SO is perceived (especially by non users). I feel you should be cautious about this image. There was no problem when careers was independent, now there might be confusion.

Comment: @bjb568 the "help" vs. "repository" debate seems semantic to me:  I can't come up with any reason one would want to create "a repository of lasting information, of answers to every programming question" unless you think those answers will in fact be of use, which means they help, no? We've always been about a repository of *useful* information, which seems to clearly imply it helps someone learn/do/build something.

Comment: If 40% of the people who visit this repository/help site are looking for jobs, then this site will be banned from my company I'm typing this from (a large scientific multinational) within the next two years.

Comment: @Jaydles My point is that the goal of satisfying the OP by doing their homework and the goal of helping future visitors by creating *lasting* information that is useful to *many* people are mutually exclusive. We need to focus on the latter and disencentivize using the site in the former way.

Comment: @Jaydles, @ bjb568, What does all that matter, if the end result is that StackOverflow becomes a job site banned from half the tech companies in the world?

Answer (score 37):

I like the idea, but how do things like Top Answers (and other site achievements) work across other sites? Some of the answers that I'm most proud of and may want to show off as part of my story to a person who wants to learn about me as a developer or a potential employer aren't on Stack Overflow, but on Programmers ([1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/716/4), [2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/186777/4), [3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/82174/4)), Project Management ([1](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/3980/30), [2](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/4266/30), [3](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/3989/30)), or The Workplace ([1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/59154/3), [2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/68/3)). Also, I think it would be pretty cool to show off that I'm a ♦ on Programmers, too.

I've read the comments, and I'm not sure if this is in addition to or in place of the CV that exists now. Something that I like is the ability to export the current CV to a PDF file. I actually do that instead of my resume. Is that feature going away? If it is, I still do have a LinkedIn profile that I maintain that can be exported to a resume-style PDF file.

---

I think that there's still a bigger picture issue here, though, and this goes to something I've said multiple times: All these posts say that they show features designed to "serve programmers better". But as someone who is both a programmer and a participant primarily on sites that aren't Stack Overflow, how are you actually serving me, a programmer?

To be totally honest, I really like these feature ideas. I like the idea of Teams and Documentation, and now this. I really like the Jobs integration into the core of Stack Overflow. But I still feel that if you aren't a "head-down into the code" developer, you're being neglected. What about the software managers and project leads? The designers and architects? The quality engineers and testers? Database administrators? People with a strong theoretical computer science background? The security-minded professionals? The [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) engineers who also participate on Server Fault? The professionals who participate in Programming Puzzles and Code Golf and want to show off their posts there? People who work as software developers, and therefore want to show off their contributions aren't on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You'll be able to put answers from other sites than Stack Overflow. The developer story will replace the Careers CV. This is why we need the community feedback, to see if something is missing :)

Comment: @StéphaneMartin That's good that I can pull answers from across the network. The only thing that may be missing that I can see is the ability to export as a PDF. I'd be slightly worried about UX, though. If you hit up someone's Developer Story page, see things from other sites, and then go to Profile and see a single site's content...that just seems weird to me. I do think that there needs to be time to look at all of the developer oriented sites in the network and how they play together, especially with respect to Teams, Documentation, Jobs, and now Developer Story.

Comment: So now it is replacing the CV? Based on the question and commentary above I was under the impression this would be in addition to the CV. @StéphaneMartin

Comment: You'll also be able to export as a PDF :).

Comment: @TinyGiant It'll replace the CV so people won't have to update their profile in 2 different places. We're also trying to create something better than a CV for developers with this developer story. And as it's hard to create something new, we need the community help :)

Comment: @StéphaneMartin Very good, then. I guess my final concern is how this looks to users (especially visitors, who may not be familiar with the SE network) when it's all hooked up. I don't want it to be clumsy when you're dealing with things that are primarily not on SO. This *could* be useful to me. All of these new features *could* be useful to me. But right now, everything is from the perspective of a user who is very active on Stack Overflow and kind of neglects other developer sites. Although I said the same thing about Teams and Documentation, too.

Answer (score 33):

I'm concerned that the "developer story" inflates the importance of StackOverflow contributions and diminishes the importance of doing a good job in the job you have. This might benefit SO in the short term by driving more traffic to the site, but you're not doing developers or employers any favors.

Developers should use StackOverflow because they want to, and because it helps them, not because they have to establish a strong SO profile in order to land a job.

If you make SO reputation an important factor in hiring decisions, you increase pressure on people to accumulate SO rep, which will lead to more problems for SO in the form of rep-whoring, dishonest voting, etc.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much time did you spend looking at the example picture? Because what I see on there are important, _non-SO oriented_ things: Positions, Certifications, Education, etc. So it seems to me like this is already going to be perfectly set for adding non-SO, job-hunt-important information.

Comment: I had the same thought when seeing this feature, but then you can hardly blame SO for being successful at what it's doing.

Comment: @Kendra And above all those non-SO things, practically right under the name, is SO (and other SE sites) reputation. And right below that, still above everything that employers normally care about, a list of your top-rated SO tags. I'm not saying there's no room for anything else, but certainly SO reputation and tags enjoy top-billing in the developer story.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't blame SO for its success, but that success is due in large part to the quality of questions and answers. SO has enough trouble already with people trying to game the system, and that'll only increase if rep becomes a more important factor in hiring decisions. Put differently, I think there's a chance that SO is taking itself too seriously, and in the long run that could damage the real value of the site.

Answer (score 27):

After the dust has partially settled, I think a better TL;DR might have been:

> **TL;DR: We're adding a radically different look to CVs**

Because:

- the "Developer Story" is replacing the CV
- existing CVs are being ported over
- it conveys all the *same information* as the CV

To me, that adds up to... It's just CVs. Re-done, in a new layout.

---

So:

### What about those of us who actually like and use the *existing* CVs?

I liked it so much that I (lazily) redirected http://meagar.net to my CV. It's my primary resumé, and I spent a lot of time making it look right. I have **no desire** to have it reformatted into some weird timeline view of the *same data*, which will render it completely unusable as a resumé.

For those of us who want a more traditional *resumé* instead of a "story", will there be an option to opt out of the Developer Story, while **still keeping our CV**?

Comment: I completely agree. I actually like the old, minimalistic CV. I definitely won't be using the new "story".

Comment: Additionally, with the death of CVs... how will we apply to jobs using SE Careers? Will we submit our Developer Stories as our resumé, or will we now be forced to upload a separate resume when we apply? I can't imagine that the Developer Story will be well-received as a resume by most hiring managers.

Comment: I think that if that had been the TL;DR from the start, the reaction might have been better. It's sad to see this battle between the staff and community.

Answer (score 22):

Even after the edits, I don't think the OP's presentation addresses the fundamental suspicion it raises with me;

> *we are the product which is being sold, and Jobs is the service being developed here*

If this is true, then the presentation should be up-front about it.  If it is not true, the presentation should explain in *much* more convincing terms how this is helping us, the users of this site.  That makes my answer basically a duplicate of "which problem is this supposed to solve, again?" comments which have been posted here in droves, but I could not see this particular aspect being addressed in comments or answers.

I'm not personally very deeply engaged in the "Let's not ever turn Stack Overflow into a social network" discussion which is so prevalent here, although obviously that is also a factor here.  Social networks can be useful and fun, but don't repeat the mistakes of LinkedIn (hostile spam factory to anybody who is not a member) or Facebook (betray the trust of your users as a matter of course).

Comment: Totally agree about linkedin, I really don't want to be a part of it and I feel it's almost obligatory to fill out my cv here, but am most ambivalent about it and toggle between making it public and private

Comment: We've always had a CV in Careers, as a part of the integration with Jobs this is our way to integrate it into SO. This isn't new feature, the CV has always been here, we're just upgrading it.

Comment: You know what they say: If you're not paying for the product, you _are_ the product. Even on SO today it is like that (with the ads).

Answer (score 17):

You're claiming that the developer story is an improvement over a classical CV, but I'm not really convinced, maybe in part because this meta post doesn't actually argue *why* this kind of structure is better.

The timeline view doesn't convince me at first glance. Mixing all kinds of information into this one timeline doesn't work well in the example screenshot for me. Some pieces of information are much more important than others, positions compared to top answer on SO for example. Not all information in there is a good fit for a timeline, it doesn't really matter all that much when that SO answer or blog post was posted. But this makes it much harder now to figure out the timeline of jobs as other information is squeezed in between there. It also seems to have less information in some parts compared to a typical CV, e.g. I can't see from the screenshot for how long the user was a developer at Github.

What problems does the timeline view solve? I see mostly drawbacks compared to a categorized view.

Another thing that doesn't look entirely right to me is the use of SO tags simply to refer to certain technologies. That might be a general issue with Careers, but it just doesn't look right to me. Someone unfamiliar with SO might wonder why that guy can't properly write MongoDB or AngularJS and instead writes in all lowercase with a dash that doesn't belong there. Tag naming and divisions are decided with the needs of SO in mind, do we also take the needs of Careers and Developer Stories into account now? Of course tags can somewhat work for this purpose, but they weren't really designed for this purpose and it shows.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I'll point out a few things - employers will have the ability to look at candidates with either a traditional sorted view or the new view; we're still working out design details but I believe we will have start/end dates on employment in this view. Part of the reason for the new view was to due with the integration of careers into SO, the existing CV had a lot of issues and since we assigned devs to integrate it, we decided to revamp the CV and make it something that users **not** looking for jobs could also use.

Comment: @bluefeet Since the entire *point* of a CV is to communicate experience and skills to employers, how could making it "something that users **not** looking for jobs could also use" possibly be an improvement? I get that there are certain similarities between a CV and a SO profile, but they're fundamentally different things. I don't necessarily want to share my CV with my SO compatriots, and I don't necessarily want to share my SO profile with prospective employers. When you apply for a job, do you enter your name as "bluefeet"?

Comment: @Caleb Say I'm a fresh out of college user who has education details, maybe a few open source projects or an app that I've worked on and I'm proud of, basically a portfolio without work experience but they want to display that to the community - there will be options to show that publicly, even if you aren't looking for a job. Then if the same user starts to job hunt, they'll have a story already filled out. As far as using aliases, the plan is to have settings in place so "bluefeet" wouldn't be the name associated with the job application. Private details will stay private for employers only.

Comment: @Caleb When it comes to sharing your CV with the rest of SO, you don't have to. You'll be able to keep it private if you want, but for those users who want to display what they've done, etc in the developer story they can.

Comment: @bluefeet I certainly hope that you guys will do a fantastic job building an interface that makes this all very clear, but right now it sounds like there's going to be one place to enter information that will be used in (at least) two very different ways. Despite unlimited funds and a horde of designers and engineers, Facebook hasn't done very well at that sort of thing. I guess I'll have to wait and see. Separate interfaces for profile and CV would make a lot more sense, with perhaps a button to populate one from the other.

Answer (score 15):

What do employers think of getting this upgraded CV?

I've applied to a few companies via careers. Several seem more open and 'start up-ish' and would be open to something like a Developer Story. However, others have been to established, large companies. I can't see someone in HR looking at a "Developer Story" and viewing it favorably when the 100s of other applications they receive are simple resumes. Sure it will make you stand out, but will it be in a good way?

Personally, I like the idea of the developer story, but I am concerned with what will be presented to potential employers when a developer applies to a job. What will *that* side of the change look like?

Comment: IIRC, the goal is to subtly discourage employers from leaning on these horrible, antiquated systems by offering something better. Of course, that won't happen overnight. Heck, there are still jobs on *our own hiring page* that require you to either upload or *plain-text paste* a CV, so it'd be a bit hypocritical if we didn't allow for that sort of thing.

Comment: Which is a great goal. Seriously. I'm concerned about the time period between now and when everyone sees the light though. I like Careers/Jobs and Developer Story looks like it'll fit in to that area well. But, I don't want to be at a disadvantage because I'm using SOJobs vs heathen developer who found a company's HR page and is working through their portal and is uploading a poorly formatted resume but that flows into their HR system much better than a "story" does.

Comment: Well, we provide an export function for this *now*, so I don't see why we'd drop that. Would kinda be shooting ourselves in the feet to say, "no large employers with tons of jobs need apply", right?

Comment: The export now, though, is a resume/CV, which makes sense because that's what I input into Careers. It has the various sections we all know - Experiences, Education, Certifications, etc. Are you saying that the Developer story will export back out to a CV with the same breakdown? I assume so, but want to make sure I understand.

Comment: @Andy Yes, you can export to the much more traditional CV / resume layout that exists right now for those companies that insist.

Comment: As someone who has recruited before, directing me to this site would remove you from my "eligible candidates" pile immediately.

Answer (score 12):

I'm concerned about merging the Careers/Jobs CV with my SO Profile.

- For me, the CV is where I want to emphasize the professional aspects of my "story".
- The SO Profile might be where I can add fun aspects of my "story" that I might not want when presenting myself as a professional.

Of course people looking for candidates can easily follow the link to my profile from the Jobs CV and see those "less-than-professional" comments, but that would be something they intend to do, not something forced upon them.

Finally, if this is something that's going to happen anyway, I'd really like to have something up front on whether I'm actively looking for a job or not. I already have enough recruiters hitting me up every day ;).

Comment: It'll be shown to employers if you actively said you're looking for a job and meet the requirements, other than that, it'd be used just for the community (and could be hidden if needed).

Answer (score 11):

I noticed some stuff on the sample timeline like "Top answer".  Does this mean that the story will be partially written by SO automatically, for example with [milestone privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=milestone)?  Or does the user have to explicitly add those kinds of on-site achievements?

Comment: Regarding on-site achievements, it'll be limited to "top answers" and they'll be added manually by users. We want to keep specific privileges under activity and profile.

Comment: I think it would be nice to be able to have some of that stuff semi-automated, i.e. pull in my top answer, but allow me to approve it for publication if it changes or something like that.

Answer (score 11):

Coming at this with the perspective of looking for new team members, I really like the idea. My gut feeling is that it's going to give me a better impression of the person than a traditional CV/resume does.

Echoing concerns from some of the comments, however, as a developer I want to reuse my existing content from elsewhere in the Stack Exchange universe, so I'd like to see the story and a combination of additional information and curated stuff from elsewhere on Stack Exchange (including from my jobs profile). And why limit it to just Stack Overflow? My questions and answers on Home Improvement can give insight into how I approach problem solving, while other sites like *[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour)*, etc. are more directly related to coding. I don't want to have to duplicate information because maintaining it becomes a nightmare. Just look at any online discussion of commenting code for an illustration of the issues that can come up.

Comment: As mentioned in the [comment to Thomas Owens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story/313971#comment289964_313966) you'll be able to include content from other sites.

Comment: Yeah, @Thomas Owens' answer wasn't showing when I started writing that...

Comment: @bluefeet We still don't know what it's going to look like for a user when you include content from other sites. I'm concerned about the UX, especially if you link to it and people who aren't familiar with how the Stack Exchange Network works find it. Careers is isolated enough from SO that it seems OK when people see content from multiple sites. But what happens when a story is populated mostly or entirely with non-SO content? Will it be confusing to people? Especially when they click the big SO link at the top, yet large amounts of your story come from Programmers or Drupal?

Comment: @ThomasOwens You raise a very good point which is partly why we brought this to the community before we have a working version.  While I don't know, at this time, what it will look like it's something we need to be aware of.

Comment: UX will definitely be a major factor, but I'd think that when I'm reading a developer's "story" it should be fairly clear when I'm reading each item why it is relevant, regardless of the source. If it's user-curated and something doesn't appear to be relevant, that in itself tells me something about that person. And if somebody is confused about Drupal answers in my "story" I'm not sure I want to be bothered by them...

Comment: @bluefeet That's good. It's just disappointing when these cool features come out, but I can't use them because the things I'm good at aren't on Stack Overflow. I think that there needs to be an appreciation that *not all programmers are on Stack Overflow* - they are on Programmers, Project Management, Workplace, Wordpress, DBA, SQA, Drupal. Unix and Linux, and so on. I think I counted over a dozen SE sites that have questions and answers related to programming / software development. More thought needs to be put into how to show off content from all of these sites to serve programmers better.

Answer (score 11):

Others have already said this but I'll say it again.

**Read what's missing only if this is true otherwise just don't**

> The end goal for this change (plus any other surprises down the line) is not to turn Stack Overflow into a social networking site (developer social network or best jobs ever)

**What's missing**

- Proficiency level on tags. Just because someone does not answer questions on something does not mean he/she doesn't know about that. Something to show self-rating of various tags. Something like [this](https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-088477606294e72f63c8059d724ca7fc?convert_to_webp=true). See left hand side under the heading **knows**
- Tag wise timeline. If I want to find when some one used a tech can I see a tag wise timeline?
- Import from LinkedIn. Many people have the information available there. Need to import somehow. e.g. Certifications
- Keep it *opt in* by default like Hats.
- Clearly state in the main post that you are not trying to turn Stack Exchange into a social network. Why? A good reason can be [this - Search "The investors"](http://www.baekdal.com/opinion/not-even-twitter-understands-twitter/). If you try to turn it into more like something else why should people not use the original thing itself?

Comment: Just a quick note regarding LinkedIn...we used to have an import from LinkedIn feature on Careers, but we recently disabled it because LinkedIn changed their TOS and the new terms did not allow us to continue offering that integration. Unless LinkedIn changes their minds, we won't be able to offer any import functionality.

Comment: @Laura Fair enough

Comment: What about import from a text file? I can save my LinkedIn profile and you folks could import it. I really don't want to re-enter all of it.

Comment: @Randgalt This seems fine but wouldn't it be tedious? Say I make a change in LinkedIn then I need to make a change here also. Also you need to mention the person

Comment: @Laura need to mention for the above comment

Comment: @Randgalt and Aseem: I no longer work at Stack Overflow, but I imagine that importing from a text file is not going to rank highly in the list of features to be implemented. It doesn't save that much work (you'll still have to remember to download from LinkedIn/upload to SO), and the data in the text file won't be structured...which means the SO software would have trouble figuring out what to put where in a profile.

Answer (score 10):

> **What happens to existing CVs just brought in from Careers?**
>
> Developer Stories are designed to replace CVs. We’ll have more details
>   on this in the future, but all existing CVs will be carried over into
>   this system, and we’ll preserve all existing privacy settings, so if
>   your profile is private the Developer Story will also be.
>
> **What if I want to keep it private?**
>
> Privacy will not be an issue: just like with existing CVs you can make
>   it completely private, or hidden on the site but searchable to
>   employers.

I do not understand this. SE profiles and jobs have overlapping information; besides that, you present this feature as if sharing information on jobs is the same as sharing information on SE.

I don't mind future employers to know what my pseudonym is on the internet. I do mind if the entire world can link my online identity to my actual name. Being at the mercy of a mentally unstable person has learned me that one should give as little information as possible to anyone on the internet, and that you'll never truly learn who a person is until it is too late.

This is why my jobs profile is not visible on StackOverflow, but my StackOverflow account is visible in my jobs profile. It is why I have the name of my university on my jobs page, but not on my StackOverflow account. It is why I have my real name on my jobs page, but am named "-" on my StackOverflow account *(yes, yes, I know, it says it is private, but SE wouldn't ask for it if they didn't use it for something, and I have no clue what it is used for)*

With this kind of integration, I don't think StackExchange understands this. I guess I'll empty out my jobs page until this change goes live...

Comment: On SO we'll use your display name, not your real name, and you'll be able to hide your developer story on SO if you want and still be visible to employers on Careers (if opt in). We take privacy really seriously and you'll still be able to use SO with no personal data and apply to jobs with personal data (only shown to employers if you opt-in).

Comment: @StéphaneMartin I always had the impression that SE takes privacy seriously, but the way the "hidden community" feature was introduced and treated so far was seriously dissappointing and makes me a bit worried about how SE treats any of the subtler privacy issues that can appear with this new feature.

Answer (score 9):

I had [some misgivings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314038/187606) about the general direction Careers is taking. While I still don't think Careers should be in the main menu, those misgivings have been reduced a lot through the team’s responses, and listening to a couple of podcasts.

So to critique the feature itself: it’s *awesome*!

- It is a visual, chronological overview of a developer’s, well, *development*; much more fun to parse than a list of positions.
- It encourages showing off your achievements to the world, which is great especially for devs who are shy or don’t want to come across as too braggy (because the story is a predefined format where it is *required* to list achievements, rather than a free-form textarea.)
- A CV is expected to be *complete*. The developer story supports *incompleteness*. You can add just the two achievements you’re most proud of, or thirty of them. That massively lowers the bar to participating in the feature.

It’s really a reinvention of the paper CV for a new medium and I like it.

Yes, it is another feature encouraging devs to show off their work to the world. Yes, that leads to some potential negative tendencies we know from Facebook or LinkedIn: it could penalize great developers who just aren’t great communicators; it could lead to too much emphasis on *appearing* competent and too little on the actual work; it is easy to fake success; etc.) But all this already applies to SO in general, too, and is ultimately a philosophical question. Do we think these potential problems outweigh the benefits? I don’t.

That it *looks* like Facebook shouldn’t be a factor in a neutral, level-headed critique. Facebook has the money to buy great UI designers; there is nothing inherently bad in following the trends they set.

It's true that features like this encourage the creation of *public* artifacts that you can show to the world. You may not like that. But it has been SO's express mission from the start. Listen to the old podcasts. I agree this is an aspect we should be careful not to *over*-emphasize (so it doesn't lose all its value!) but it's always been in the site's DNA and part of its success.

**Downsides / suggestions:**

- I could see this being more difficult in terms of getting a complete picture of a person’s employment history, the kind recruiters need so they can ask questions like „I see you moved from x position at y to z position at n 15 months after you started out at y; why didn’t you try to advance to x position at y instead?“ But I’m not a recruiter so I don’t know, and I suppose they will get to keep the CV.
- There should be ways to distinguish between major and minor events. „Checked in three-line patch to project XYZ“ needs to look different from „got a job at Google“.
- I personally would never add a visible „what I’ve been reading“ section to my profile and I’m not sure the system should encourage it. I get what it is trying to convey, but to me, a huge "what I’ve been reading" section sometimes makes people look a bit lame. It’s just… trying too hard to do all the right things. Dropping in stuff like „I realized from what xyz says in abc that…“ in the personal statement or a conversation just seems so much cooler. YMMV.
- The name feels a bit off, at least if it's going to be displayed publicly. There's no better way to kill the magic of storytelling than calling it storytelling. I'd much prefer something neutral like "timeline".

Comment: Regarding the last point... I feel the name "Developer Yarn" was rejected without proper consideration.

Comment: @Shog9 "Developer Epic"?

Comment: I've got to say @Pekka웃, I really appreciate the fact that you took the time to write this up after chewing on the feature for a bit.  The feedback is really helpful. IIRC, we are planning on showing the start/end dates for positions and employers will still be able to view the details in a sorted way, so that should take care of your first downside. At this time, I don't think we're 100% sold in the name, but naming is hard.  I'm also working on a follow-up post to get out in the next few days to address some of the questions/concerns raised by the original post.

Answer (score 8):

#### What might be missing

I often see users using their profile to:

- List their own favorite contributions (questions and answers)
- List their best achievements (badges and tag badges)
- Provide a donation wishlist (books and assets)

#### Concerns

Unclear tech stack flexibility:

- Can I add a tag to the tech stack that I didn't have contributed on Stack Overflow yet, but I have a great experience with? [*Yes*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story/313970#comment289978_313970)

Comment: Yes you can add tags you didn't have contributed on Stack Overflow yet in the tech stack. You'll be able to showcase technologies you're great at, no matter your reputation.

Answer (score 7):

> **TL;DR:**
>
> We're replacing CVs with something you can use even if you aren't currently looking for a job.

**TL;DR;** *Customizability is important*

1. Replacing CV/Portfolio is a bad idea, this should be a separate feature; since they represent two different things.
2. Developer Story should be customizable, utilizing things like favorites & options to control statistics.
3. The term "Developer Story" would lead employers to assume it means the timline of your professional projects & honorable jobs they had over the years, as a developer. Technically, this isn't your story as a developer, it is your story on Stack Overflow.
4. Statistics should show where most of your contributions are, in relation to tag-groups. Tag-groups are like the group of tags related to database, like transaction, sql, plsql, ..etc. Leaving customizing this to the user would solve its shortcomings.

Comment: The developer story is fully customizable and reflects things about you as a developer, not about you on SO.

Comment: +1 for your avatar! (oh, and I agree with what you say ;))

Comment: The developer story allows you to bring things _outside_ of Stack Overflow to your profile - like work you've done in open source or talks you've given. Or that blog post you wrote when you just got so fed up with [language] that your hair turned green and started singing 70s show tunes. It's only for employers insofar as how much you're looking for a job. Primarily, it's just for you, and yeah - it could help get you hired if that's what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Are two views needed, one for HR people, and another for the project manager that do understand how programmers think?

Otherwise there is a risk that by including something in your story that will be understood by the project manager, you will confuse the HR person and your story will never be seen by the project manager.

Comment: Employers will be able to view either the story view or a sorted view, which will be similar to a resume.

Comment: @bluefeet, that still does not help with trying to target cooperate HR types and project managers given they have a very different outlook on life.

Answer (score 6):

I've been ambivalent about the CV and actually toggle it between being public and private for that reason.

SO for me, has been a place I can come to for relaxation, education and to improve my programming skills. In fact the more pressure I'm under in my (outside SO life) programming the more questions I answer here, as a stress relief. So the idea of integrating my escape and refuge with my employment is counter productive for my experience here.

And just having it there and all the fan fare does feel like pressure from S.E.

It also feels like a sell out, it's a way for S.E. to make more $, get more views and expand it's platform. The one thing S.E. does better than anywhere (in my opinion) is have an online programming repository and Q&A site, it does this the best, and I honestly don't believe many of the other areas S.E. branches into are not comparable to S.O. programmers.se and the like, I think trying to be all things to all people (or as many as possible in this case) somehow degrades the credibility of the site.

Oh and once I started to fill out my cv, I cannot eliminate the technologies I want to work with, it only provides for a min of two tags, so it's not optional to opt out.

Comment: *So the idea of integrating my escape and refuge with my employment* it already is integrated. It will just look different and can be found with a different button

Comment: @TimCastelijns I understand that, I don't like it.

Comment: FWIW, I can sympathize with this. There are *very* few times in my life I'd have wanted anything approaching a complete career history available online, to potential employers or anyone else - and particularly not integrated with one of the sites I used to blow off steam after work! That said, right from the start there've been people who've considered Stack Overflow to be their public portfolio and used their profiles to this end; I think there's room here to serve both groups.

Answer (score 5):

**Ideas**

1. For privacy options I would advice to avoid putting anything that requires individual permissions; meaning getting email requests from lots of different people on my individual Story profile. That is something people can email you about.
2. Allow us to manually approve all of the content that will be displayed in the Story.
3. Regarding our Interests, allow us to select our *favored* Stack Exchange posts and add them to our Story. This can tie in very well if we want to link our interests with our Careers profile.
4. Can Stories show the things we have the most current interest on? Whether it be personal or Stack Exchange related?
5. How will Story have transparency between Admin and non Admin users?

**Criticism**:

1. How can - Certified in X - be a reliable and provable content to add to Story?
2. What is the value of having a Story when compared to a Careers profile?
3. Not everyone asks great answers/questions and not everyone gets many views/votes either despite the effort. How can your effort or lack thereof reflect positively on the Story?
4. If our story sucks (because we spend more time doing things outside Stack Exchange for example), can we choose not to have one?

Comment: Regarding your criticisms: 1) if you lied on a resume, most likely an employer will discover that, 2) the developer story is going to be a replacement of the Careers CV you won't have the details in multiple places, 3) If you don't have tons of votes on an answer, it doesn't necessarily mean you aren't proud of it. I've got good answers with minimal votes and I might choose to showcase it based on the content of the answer, 4) it's not going to be required to complete the story, but you'll be able to showcase things that you want even if it's not complete.

Answer (score 5):

I think this should be just an optional extension to show some stuff you are proved about. However how is that relevant for someone else?

In the first plain facts are interesting. The current CV provides those informations perfectly IMHO.

If you would like to hire someone you might be interested in checking what that dev thinks about he has done. This should be optional and not mandatory. Not every developer likes it to maintain those stories, and Stack Overflow is no Social Network where it is important to show what you are doing just now. (This is the reason why I don't use Facebook and co)

In general I like the idea to point out some things you are proved about, but this should not replace our CV!

Comment: Employers will have 2 views for CVs, they will be able to view your details in a sorted manner (similar to a traditional resume) or the new story version.  We're still of course working out all the details which is why we brought this to the community for feedback.

Answer (score 5):

I do not care to reveal my date of graduation from university.  Please make the date fields optional.

Meanwhile, my developer story does none of us any good, because it looks like I did not go to college.

Comment: I might suggest [posting some of this as a feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) here on MSO and including the tag developer-story. This will most likely get lost as answer here.

Answer (score 5):

Not a fan of the new system.

I want to emphasize what I want to emphasize, not the last things I happened to touch. Just because I submitted patches to 20 open source projects doesn't mean I want that at the top of my *story* with my more relevant and marketable experience buried several screens below the fold.

Answer (score 3):

After learning that this will in fact export to a nicely formatted CV (similar to the current one) then I personally find no reason to not want this.  I think this is a pretty clean change that fits well with the jobs integration of SO.

Before you go downvoting and ranting about this post remember this isn't all about **you**.  Most comments or answers here state

> I wouldn't use this / I don't want this / I'm not looking for a job

Please stop and consider that one day, yes one day, you too maybe looking for a job.  At the end of the day the developer story showcases your talent.  Companies (at least good companies) are changing nowadays.  These companies love seeing stuff like this.

At the end of the day this thing translates to a CV, so for those who are concerned about that this can still serve as your exported CV.  But to those who may have a lot of projects (github) this is a good place to keep all of this activity.  The great thing is, if you don't want this information public then you simply don't put it on the site.

Before you bash this consider how it could help you and think long term, not just today but tomorrow.  True story: A co-worker of mine, who was an intern, recently wanted to be brought in full time at the company we are at.  Unfortunately, some company policy stated he could not be full time and have full time benefits without first graduating.  He was able to use SO Jobs to help find a new career, that gave him (in writing) that upon graduation he would have a full time job.  The current company he was working at could not meet his needs.  SO Jobs gave him that opportunity.

So please, stop think and first try something out before giving up so easily.  You all sound like my grandma when we upgraded her from Windows XP to Windows 7.

Comment: Your "Before you bash..." is, if anything, a defence of the **current** system. Why change something that clearly worked very well for your coworker? And your "grandma" statement is just offensive. We are not luddites because we want to be told *why* radical changes are being made to existing systems that people are successfully using.

Comment: @meagar - because about 3-4 weeks ago I couldn't say the same thing as careers was seperate from SO.  He didn't even know careers existed nor did he have any inclination to look for it.  When it was integrated within SO is when he got his golden ticket.  I use this as an example to what could happen with the feature of the developer story.

Comment: If stating your rants are similiar to when we upgraded my grandma is offensive I don't know what world you are in.  Relax, take a chill pill, life will turn whether you like it or not.  Give me a break.

Comment: We're not talking about the careers/SO unification. This isn't that. All your points in favor of Developer Stories are really points in favor of [the careers unification](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow) which is a separate issue altogether.

Comment: No it means to accept change and give it a chance.  I know where I am posting.  Its clearly related to my post.

Comment: Your argument that we should just "accept change" is based on your belief that one specific change (careers unification) was responsible for one specific good thing happening (your friend getting a job)? It's a pretty tenuous connection to say we should just "accept change and give it a chance" based on *one* experience with an unrelated change.

Comment: My example, was just that an example.  When someone gives you an example, they don't say 100% will benefit, they give you an example.  Whether you like it or not is just that **you** no one else.

Comment: This actually *is* part of Integration, @meagar... Weird though that probably seems. Right now, things like CVs are just the output of old Careers code piped through an infernal machine; the long-term goal is to actually integrate the code as well as the UI (so that it isn't so foreign and out of place, and also so we're not maintaining so much duplicate stuff). This is the first step. The design may be a *little bit* ambitious, but hey - better to aim high & scale back as needed than slavishly copy the boring status quo and get nothing tangible for the effort.

Comment: Downvoted for the "you sound like my grandma..." quip.  It is quite disrespectful, both to those engaged in this discussion, and to grandmas.

Comment: @WayneConrad - No grandmas, including mine were affected by anything I said.

Comment: @Shog9 That's fine, but there is no reason that porting the feature to a new system necessitates *completely redesigning that feature*.

Comment: You're right, there isn't @meagar. On the other hand, if we're gonna invest the resources in porting it, shouldn't we try & get something extra out of it? AFAIK, the idea here was to try & make the CV feature a bit more of a multitasker - something that could still benefit folks who aren't into Careers / Jobs. The more people it benefits, the more worthwhile the investment in developer time. And the more people who use it, the more feedback we get and the better we can make it - which you may have noticed was sort of a big pain-point for Careers features in the past.

Comment: @Shog9 I think part of the problem is that arguments for integration are being presented as arguments for Developer Stories, as though the only form an integrated CVs product could take is that of Developer Stories. Nobody (well, at least not me) is arguing against integrating the two systems; I just fail to see why the necessary solution to "integrating CVs" is being presented as Developer Stories. Yes, more users + more feedback is great, but... doesn't it make sense to get more users + more feedback on the *existing* system, by slavishly porting the status quo?

Comment: @Shog9 I mean, once you have more users + more feedback coming out of an integrated CV system, you could use all that feedback to make a case for or against transitioning to something like Dev Stories. I don't know, maybe you guys have done a ton of user testing and there are solid reasons to think Dev Stories is the right direction for the product? But most of what have been presented is the argument that "integration is good, therefore we propose developer stories", which is a bit of a non-sequitur.

Comment: Not particularly, @meagar - that was the point of the integration "hack" put in place a couple weeks ago. You can see what a slavish port would look like (more or less) right now; the fact that it's running separately under the hood is hidden well enough to get the idea. Now... It's absolutely legitimate to look at that & say, "I like this better than what's being proposed to replace it". Sooner or later, we *will* re-write CVs, and the more feedback we get now the easier it'll be to decide what that ends up looking like.

Comment: @Shog9 Well then... is the intent here to suggest Developer Stories as a *proposed* feature, and gather feedback? Or is it to announce to the community that Developer Stories is coming? You're making it sound now like the final form is unclear and still subject to big changes, while the original post and mockup seems to indicate that the form is pretty fixed.

Comment: @meagar - I'm not sure what industry you work in, but when it comes to stuff like this its an endless cycle.  There is no final form of anything IT related.  Of course Developer Stories is coming, but that doesn't mean it will be perfect.  It's the first beta phase of it.  Nothing is pretty fixed, just because of the screen captures doesn't mean its 100% complete.  Remember the post on job unificintegration or whatever the heck it was.  After that post was made I filled over 100 bugs / feature requests..that too had screen shots.  That simply doesn't mean it was fully done bug free...

Comment: If it was fixed, we'd be telling you to go try it out, @meagar. Right now, it's a designer mock-up; until a few days ago, all the entries in that screenshot read, "lorem ipsum". No matter how convinced we might be that it's the cat's pajamas, we're nowhere near confident enough to actually build it without talking to folks here first; all feedback is welcome, and we'll try to make wise decisions based on what y'all tell us - doesn't mean we won't try something new, but a good argument in favor of doing something else is always worthwhile.

Answer (score -1):

I like it fine. I wish you could link to an item when sharing.

Answer (score -1):

Well... goodby then! I'm sure a lot will miss you and others won't even know you ever existed!

> So long, and thanks for all the fish!

Answer (score -2):

#### I like the idea.

Yeah, it's all right. There's always those people who are just keen to dislike new features. That was never surprising, you know, and with things like the upgrades of Windows, and so on, people liked to dislike new features, but eventually they fell in love with it.

Developer Story is pretty much the greatest way I can show **who am I** to whatever employer. It's a rather a fascinating way to see the details and actually see how professional that developer is.

CVs and Resumes are pretty nifty, with proper styling you can get them to look so beautiful, but then, it's all "I worked at X" and "I studied at Y". Although these are necessary information, they really don't cover who the developer actually is. That is almost the same as looking at the specification of a computer without seeing or using it.

Developer Story is a good thing that Stack Overflow should finally introduce us, nearly all developers spend a fascinating time here, and it'd be great to establish a connection between our CV and our favorite developer website.

Answer (score -4):

**I don't dislike it.**

I see a lot of people saying "No I don't like this !". <del>If you do not like it, please feel free to not use it.</del>. *After reading again(posts and comments), now i think there should be an option to stick to the old version for those people who does not like the new UI.*

In my honest opinion, I don't think this is such a bad idea and i will use this. To me, it looks like a redesign of the CV page with a nice UI. I really don't care it look like social network XYZ's timeline or whatever. This is more like a "About me" page for a developer where things are listed/shown in a nice and clean way.

Those HR people who pick resumes with Javascript keyword for a Java opening, Send them your normal resume when you apply in those companies.

**Things i do not wish to see in future**

1. Adding Background image on your profile page
2. Adding "Favourite/Like/Follow  this developer" feature
3. Adding "Connections"/"People I worked with" or something like that.(*I know team page exists!*)
4. Adding endorsements ! ( We have SO reputation which speaks for itself)
5. Slideshows of your works/projects !
6. Embed twitter feed !

BTW, The UI looks clean. Good work.

Comment: They're replacing one feature with a radically different feature. "If you don't like it, don't use it" is hardly a valid response when they're *taking away* something we're already using, and replacing it with something we might not want. If you (like me) actually *like* the existing CVs, then this is a pretty bad change for you.

Comment: **all existing CVs will be carried over into this system**. To me, It looks like moving your data to a different look and feel UI with some additional stuff in the future.

Comment: @Shyju Then why say *"If you do not like it, please feel free to not use it."*? If I used the old CV, I am essentially being forced to use the new one.

Comment: That is true. This made me rethink and i agree that they should let people keep the old version if they want. But i personally like to try  the new one.