# Developer story auto-created on "Dismiss" click

Tags: bug, developer-story

I fall into the camp of [not seeing value in the Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story). That said, I clicked "Developer Story" for the first time in my profile and was presented with a form to fill out. Not wanting to fill out the form, I clicked "Dismiss". This automatically created the Developer story, and forwarded me to my "timeline". This was not expected.

I understand that I cannot delete my Developer Story, which is an issue unto itself, however the auto-creation of this when I explicitly clicked "Dismiss" is shady at best. In what UX paradigm does clicking "Dismiss" on something, actually create it?

This seems like an underhanded way to force people to use DS, and I disagree with the approach.

Comment: Just to clarify, you actually had a developer story already because you had a Careers CV which was imported to your Developer Story.  What you triggered were the prompts for you to complete your story and possibly job preferences. We know that this needs improvement and team is going to be addressing that soon.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks very much for the clarification, much appreciated.