# What is the difference between Developer CV and Developer Story?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I've seen a few discussions on Stack Overflow using "Developer CV" and "Developer Story" interchangeably when discussing their career profile.

Is there a difference between my Developer CV and my Developer Story?

Comment: Yes, "CV" is the old classic view. Developer Story is [the new view introduced fairly recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313960/introducing-the-developer-story).

Comment: @CodyGray Should meta questions about CV's be edited to refer to Developer Stories, or should they be closed as "***Can no longer be reproduced***"

Comment: They are still two completely separate views, so...neither?

Comment: @CodyGray Oh? So both are still available then? I didn't see a tag for [developer-cv]

Comment: Yeah, there isn't a tag because that's the original view, so there was no need to differentiate. Compare: `https://stackoverflow.com/story/UserName` vs. `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/UserName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our career profile has two views to it:

- Story View - the Developer Story timeline view where items are placed chronologically instead of in categories together
- Traditional View - this is where your career history is presented in a CV view where items are shown bucketed together in categories like Experience, Education, etc

The difference between the two is how your career history is being displayed.

Comment: You got to admit - it is all very confusing for something we used to call a resume.  When you "apply for a job" it says it will upload a version of your developer CV.  But here your answer says there is a story view / traditional view.  Why don't you explicitly use those terms instead of CV / Resume if that is the new way.  When you apply for a job you should state "We will attach a copy of your TRADITIONAL VIEW for this application".  It is also so very confusing even to power users.  In terms of jobs you guys have really mislead programmers.